# How to change gpg-agent directory

Tags: gnupg, pgp

I was trying to do `git-crypt unlock`. However, I got this error:

```
gpg: error running '/usr/local/Cellar/gnupg/2.3.1/bin/gpg-agent': probably not installed
gpg: failed to start gpg-agent '/usr/local/Cellar/gnupg/2.3.1/bin/gpg-agent': Configuration error
gpg: can't connect to the gpg-agent: Configuration error
git-crypt: GPG error: gpg --list-secret-keys failed
```

The reason is it is looking for the wrong path. There is no path as '/usr/local/Cellar/gnupg/2.3.1/bin/gpg-agent'. My pgp-agent is actually in this folder
`/opt/brew/bin/gpg-agent`

My question is how can I change the path to correct the `pgp-agent` directory?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.